# Why cannot Nginx access files in the `wp-includes` directory?

Tags: linux, nginx, php-fpm, wordpress

I have a WordPress website that I installed on an Ubuntu server. I setup Nginx to listen for requests and to push them to php-fpm. I am using the `pool` feature so that the WordPress site can have all the files and directories owned by the user that operates the site. I am using the [suggested file permissions](https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/server/file-permissions/) of `755` on directories and `640` on files.

The website loads, except for certain files that are in the `wp-includes` directory. I can use the Admin Dashboard, except again for certain things that are needed from the `wp-includes` directory.

Here are some of the errors that I am seeing in the `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

```
2023/10/24 00:38:26 [error] 2611#2611: *10600 open() "/home/user1/www/example.com/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css"               failed (13: Permission denied), client: 10.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=6.3.2 HTTP/1.1",                              host: "www.example.com", referrer: "http://www.example.com/"
2023/10/24 00:38:26 [error] 2611#2611: *10602 open() "/home/user1/www/example.com/wp-includes/blocks/navigation/view.min.js"       failed (13: Permission denied), client: 10.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/blocks/navigation/view.min.js?ver=886680af40b7521d60fc HTTP/1.1",       host: "www.example.com", referrer: "http://www.example.com/"
2023/10/24 00:38:26 [error] 2611#2611: *10603 open() "/home/user1/www/example.com/wp-includes/blocks/navigation/style.min.css"     failed (13: Permission denied), client: 10.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/blocks/navigation/style.min.css?ver=6.3.2 HTTP/1.1",                    host: "www.example.com", referrer: "http://www.example.com/"
2023/10/24 00:38:26 [error] 2611#2611: *10604 open() "/home/user1/www/example.com/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css"               failed (13: Permission denied), client: 10.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=6.3.2 HTTP/1.1",                              host: "www.example.com", referrer: "http://www.example.com/"
2023/10/24 00:38:26 [error] 2611#2611: *10605 open() "/home/user1/www/example.com/wp-includes/blocks/navigation/view-modal.min.js" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 10.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/blocks/navigation/view-modal.min.js?ver=b478fa3cd1475dec97d3 HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "http://www.example.com/"
2023/10/24 00:38:26 [error] 2611#2611: *10604 open() "/home/user1/www/example.com/wp-includes/js/admin-bar.min.js"                 failed (13: Permission denied), client: 10.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/js/admin-bar.min.js?ver=6.3.2 HTTP/1.1",                                host: "www.example.com", referrer: "http://www.example.com/"
2023/10/24 00:38:26 [error] 2611#2611: *10603 open() "/home/user1/www/example.com/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.min.js"             failed (13: Permission denied), client: 10.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/js/comment-reply.min.js?ver=6.3.2 HTTP/1.1",                            host: "www.example.com", referrer: "http://www.example.com/"
2023/10/24 00:38:26 [error] 2611#2611: *10605 open() "/home/user1/www/example.com/wp-includes/js/hoverintent-js.min.js"            failed (13: Permission denied), client: 10.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/js/hoverintent-js.min.js?ver=2.2.1 HTTP/1.1",                           host: "www.example.com", referrer: "http://www.example.com/"
```

Why would Nginx have access to everything except for things in the `wp-includes` directory?

These are the directory listings for each of the referenced files:

```
# ls -al /home
drwxr-xr-x  4 user1 user1 4096 Oct 23 20:52 user1
# ls -al /home/user1/
drwxr-xr-x 3 user1 user1 4096 Oct 23 21:35 www
# ls -al /home/user1/www/
drwxr-xr-x 5 user1 user1 4096 Oct 23 21:52 example.com
# ls -al /home/user1/www/example.com/
-rw-r-----  1 user1 user1   405 Feb  6  2020 index.php
-rw-r-----  1 user1 user1 19915 Jan  1  2023 license.txt
-rw-r-----  1 user1 user1  7399 Jul  5 21:41 readme.html
-rw-r-----  1 user1 user1  7211 May 13 01:35 wp-activate.php
drwxr-xr-x  9 user1 user1  4096 Oct 12 23:12 wp-admin
-rw-r-----  1 user1 user1   351 Feb  6  2020 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-r-----  1 user1 user1  2323 Jun 14 18:11 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-r-----  1 user1 user1  3013 Feb 23  2023 wp-config-sample.php
-r--------  1 user1 user1  3329 Oct 23 21:52 wp-config.php
drwxr-xr-x  5 user1 user1  4096 Oct 24 00:46 wp-content
-rw-r-----  1 user1 user1  5638 May 30 22:48 wp-cron.php
drwxr-xr-x 27 user1 user1 12288 Oct 12 23:12 wp-includes
-rw-r-----  1 user1 user1  2502 Nov 27  2022 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-r-----  1 user1 user1  3927 Jul 16 16:16 wp-load.php
-rw-r-----  1 user1 user1 49441 Jul 17 17:18 wp-login.php
-rw-r-----  1 user1 user1  8537 Jun 22 18:36 wp-mail.php
-rw-r-----  1 user1 user1 25602 Jul 25 10:35 wp-settings.php
-rw-r-----  1 user1 user1 34385 Jun 19 22:27 wp-signup.php
-rw-r-----  1 user1 user1  4885 Jun 22 18:36 wp-trackback.php
-rw-r-----  1 user1 user1  3236 Jun 14 18:11 xmlrpc.php

# ls -al /home/user1/www/example.com/wp-includes
drwxr-xr-x 95 user1 user1   4096 Oct 12 23:12 blocks
drwxr-xr-x  3 user1 user1   4096 Oct 12 23:12 css
drwxr-xr-x 13 user1 user1   4096 Oct 12 23:12 js

# ls -al /home/user1/www/example.com/wp-includes/blocks/
drwxr-xr-x  2 user1 user1   4096 Oct 12 23:12 navigation

# ls -al /home/user1/www/example.com/wp-includes/blocks/navigation
-rw-r-----  1 user1 user1 16081 Jul 19 15:13 style.min.css
-rw-r-----  1 user1 user1  7814 Jun 29 00:08 view-modal.min.js
-rw-r-----  1 user1 user1  1136 Jun 27 18:24 view.min.js

# ls -al /home/user1/www/example.com/wp-includes/css/
-rw-r-----  1 user1 user1 20319 Feb 11  2023 admin-bar.min.css
-rw-r-----  1 user1 user1 59016 Mar  4  2021 dashicons.min.css

# ls -al /home/user1/www/example.com/wp-includes/js
-rw-r-----  1 user1 user1   3536 Feb  2  2023 admin-bar.min.js
-rw-r-----  1 user1 user1   2981 Apr  9  2022 comment-reply.min.js
-rw-r-----  1 user1 user1   1718 Dec 10  2019 hoverintent-js.min.js
```

`nginx website config file`:

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /home/user1/www/example.com;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "display_errors=0;\n error_reporting=E_ALL;";
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm-www.example.com.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
}
```

`/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/user1-domain.conf`:

```
[example.com]
user = user1
group = user1
listen = /run/php/php-fpm-www.example.com.sock;
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 25
```

Versions:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
PHP 8.1
php8.1-fpm
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `.htaccess`? Notably the one in `wp-includes` if there is one.

Comment: SELinux, AppArmor, whatever like this? What is in *other* log files on your system? @tsc_chazz **Nginx** never parses and checks `.htaccess`.

Comment: There are no `.htaccess` files, as Nikita said. @NikitaKipriyanov, I am not running SELinux or AppArmor. I have not yet found anything useful in other logs.

Comment: nginx runs under www-data and not user1

Answer (score 0):

The static files are served directly by `nginx` and not `php-fpm` so they need to be accessible by the user that `nginx` uses, usually `www-data`. You can either include the user `user1` in the group `www-data` or other way around, include the user `www-data` in the group `user1`.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through some more documentation ([Changing File Permissions](https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/server/file-permissions/) and [Hardening WordPress: File Permissions](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/hardening-wordpress/#file-permissions)) I realized that on my system I was going to use some permissions that were not at strict.

I had been trying directories with `750` and files with `640`. When I gave `world` read access, things started to work.

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

I did not have to change ownership to `www-data` on anything so far. The `php-fpm` user and group settings seem to be doing great:

```
user = user1
group = user1
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

That allows Nginx to run as `www-data` and access the site through `fpm` as `user1`.